# SQL exact match within a pattern?

Tags: sql, quickbooks

I am using qodbc (a quickbooks database connector) It uses an ODBC-like sql language.

I would like to find all the records where a field matches a pattern but I have a slight delema.

The information in my field looks like this:

```
 321-......02/25/10
 321-1.....02/26/10
 321-2.....03/25/10
 321-3.....03/26/10
 322-......04/25/10
 322-1.....04/26/10
 322-2.....05/25/10
 322-3.....05/26/10
```

I would like my query to return only the rows where the pattern matches the first number. So if the user searches for '321' it will only show records that look like 321 but not those that have 321-1 or 321-3. Similarly if the user searched for 321-1 you would not see 321. (that's the easy part)

Right now I have

```
 LIKE '321%'
```

This finds all of them regardless of if they are followed by dots or not. Is there a way I can limit the query to only specifics despite that field having more information that it should.

(P.S. I did not set up this system, it makes me wince to see two data points in one field
I'm sorry if my title isn't right, suggest a new title if you can. )

Comment: your question is not clear to me.  can you post expected output?

Comment: In `qodbc` are you able to create stored procedures or are all your queries dynamic sql?

Comment: why not use "like '321-.%'" in that case?

Comment: User input '321' Expected output 321-......02/25/10

Comment: I don't think it handles stored procedure, either I don't know how to use the documentation or it's pretty lacking in that department. It talks about the different settings but not so much the syntax besides saying it is ODBC compliant

Comment: Andrew Cooke's Reply seems to work, What does the period(.) wildcard represent. I can only find what it means in regex is it the same meaning?

Comment: Oh i see what you did there, very clever!!!

Answer (score 2):

LIKE '321%' AND NOT LIKE '321-%'

Comment: data set is the same, but that would still show 321-1,321-2,321-3 which is a no no